# Toggle a DIV without toggling all similarly named DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a Q&A test prep and there are several questions each followed by four possible answers and then below the answers there is an "Answer" button that reveals the true answer. I got everything working fine up until I realized that I have it so any "Answer" button will toggle all of the content DIVs. How do I make it that the "Answer" button only toggles open the "content" div that precedes it?

Keep in mind that I cannot assign unique IDs as there are hundreds of questions and I'm trying to save time.

jQuery:

```
$(function() {  
   $(".answer").click(function() {  
      $(".content").toggle("slow");  
   });  
});
```

CSS:

```
div.content {  
   display: none;  
   width: 300px;  
   height: auto;  
   margin: 10px;  
   padding: 20px;  
   background: white;  
   border: 1px solid black;  
   cursor: pointer;  
}

button.answer {  
   font-family: sans-serif;  
   font-weight: bold;  
   font-style: normal;  
   font-size: 0.92em;  
   line-height: 1.36em;  
   text-indent: 0em;  
   text-align: left;  
   color: #000000;  
   margin: 1em 0em 0em 2em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="keep">
  <p class="q"><samp class="q-no">1.</samp> Interpret the following directions:</p>
  <p class="q-equation">i cap po qid × 10d</p>
  <p class="an"><span class="choice">a.</span> Take one capsule by mouth four times a day for ten days.</p>
  <p class="an"><span class="choice">b.</span> Take one capsule by mouth three times a day for ten days.</p>
  <p class="an"><span class="choice">c.</span> Take one capsule by mouth twice a day for ten days.</p>
  <p class="an"><span class="choice">d.</span> Take one capsule by mouth once a day for ten days.</p>

  <div class="content">
    <p class="anl"><b>a.</b> Take one capsule by mouth four times a day for ten days. Remember: <i>qd</i> is once a day, <i>bid</i> is twice a day, <i>tid</i> is three times a day and <i>qid</i> is four times a day.</p><a id="anchor-25-anchor"></a>
  </div>
  <button class="answer">Answer</button>
</div>

<div class="keep">
  <p class="q"><samp class="q-no">2.</samp> Interpret the following directions:</p>
  <p class="q-equation">ii tab po tid × 7d.</p>
  <p class="an"><span class="choice">a.</span> Take two tablets by mouth four times a day for seven days.</p>
  <p class="an"><span class="choice">b.</span> Take two tablets by mouth three times a day for seven days.</p>
  <p class="an"><span class="choice">c.</span> Take two tablets by mouth twice a day for seven days.</p>
  <p class="an"><span class="choice">d.</span> Take two tablets by mouth once a day for seven days.</p>

  <div class="content">
    <p class="anl" id="anchor-25-anchor"><b>b.</b> Take two tablets by mouth three times a day for seven days.</p><a id="anchor-26-anchor"></a>
  </div>
  <button class="answer">Answer</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using the [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) function:

```
$(function() {  
    $(".answer").click(function() {  
        $(this).prev().toggle("slow");  
    });  
});
```

If `.content` won't always be directly before `.answer`, use `.prev('.content')` instead.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks, that worked great and it was so simple. I'm very, very new to jQuery and this has been very helpful. I've been Googling for six hours and found nothing that worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {  
   $(".answer").click(function() {  
   $(this).prev(".content").toggle("slow");  
   });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to `this` in your click handler to identify the button that was clicked and then find the previous sibling that represents the content you want to show like this:

```
$(".answer").click(
    $(this).prev().toggle("slow");
);
```